# Changed image color after fetch from database

Tags: java, jdbc

I have problem with fetching image from database in Java. I wrote this function:

```
public byte[] fetchPhoto(Long id) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
        byte[] photo = null;
        Blob imageBlob = null;
        try (ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement()
                .executeQuery("select IMAGE from IMAGE_TABLE where IMAGE_ID = " + id)) {

            while (rs.next()) {
                imageBlob = rs.getBlob(1);
                photo = imageBlob.getBytes(1, (int) imageBlob.length());
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(conn, dataSource);
        }
        return photo;
    }
```

Ok, I have fetched image, but effect is like :
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHybt.jpg)

Orginal image
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SGZz.png)

I don't know why after fetch I have this color. I checked this image in database so here is ok.

Comment: can you paste the two data where you can get while debugging?

Comment: This is a completely different image, it is smaller, and has an extra circle on it. You must do some processing on it that you did not show.

Comment: @Henry fetched is the same photo, but I used some component to display it(it's web app), so you don't care about it. For test I write it immediately to file and I have the same effect, so is error is not in component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need solution like [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/convert-png-to-jpeg-image-file-in-java/). So using this example, here is your improved method:

```
public byte[] fetchPhoto(Long id) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
        byte[] photo = null;
        Blob imageBlob = null;
        try (ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement()
                .executeQuery("select IMAGE from IMAGE_TABLE where IMAGE_ID = " + id)) {

            while (rs.next()) {
                imageBlob = rs.getBlob(1);
                photo = imageBlob.getBytes(1, (int) imageBlob.length());
                ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(photo);
                BufferedImage bf = ImageIO.read(bais);
                BufferedImage nbf = new BufferedImage(bf.getWidth(),
                        bf.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                nbf.createGraphics().drawImage(bf, 0, 0, Color.WHITE, null);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(nbf, "jpg", baos);
                photo = baos.toByteArray();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(conn, dataSource);
        }
        return photo;
    }
```

If I were you I moved this code to separete method.